# How Do I preview Links in my Flutter Project

Tags: firebase, flutter, hyperlink, preview

I have a chat app I'm working on and I noticed that while sending messages, it doesnt recogise the links sent. But I want the links to be recognised and preview shown. How do I go about that please. And if there are any dependencies needed. Thank you.

I'm new to flutter so I'd like details, Thank you

Comment: You can use this plugin: https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_link_preview

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [flutter_link_previewer](https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_link_previewer) package.
Here is a usage example from the documentation:

```dart
import 'package:flutter_link_previewer/flutter_link_previewer.dart';

LinkPreview(
  enableAnimation: true,
  onPreviewDataFetched: (data) {
    setState(() {
      // Save preview data to the state              
    });
  },
  previewData: _previewData, // Pass the preview data from the state
  text: 'https://flyer.chat',
  width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
)
```